# Symfony displaying user account information after log in in template

Tags: php, security, symfony, account

Can someone point me to a tutorial or direction where I can have my webpage display user's account information  after they have logged in? For example, after a successful login they are redirected to the access page and somewhere either on the top right or left I can display the user's name and have a log out option, as well as clicking on their name to go to a page where they can change their passwords. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can access logged in user in twig using `{{ app.user }}`.

For example, `{{ app.user.email }}` will display user's email.

Comment: This is accessing the User Entity in the database?

Comment: `app.user` holds user object of currently logged in user. Yes, it is loaded from database.

Answer (score 0):

As explain in the documentation :
http://symfony.com/doc/master/book/security.html#retrieving-the-user-object

**Retreive User object**

```
$user = $this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
```

**In a Controller**

```
$user = $this->getUser();
```

**In a template**

*TWIG*

```
<p>Username: {{ app.user.username }}</p>
```

*PHP*

```
<p>Username: <?php echo $app->getUser()->getUsername() ?></p>
```